# Print test output during tests in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, pytest

In PyCharm, I want be able to see stdout and stderr in the console **DURING** PyTest test execution (not after).  I often use breakpoints and the expression evaluator tool to print or display the output of some code (for example, using spark's `dataframe.show()`), but because by default, pytest collects the system output, it is not displayed in PyCharm until the end of test run, which is not nearly as useful if executing multiple debugging expressions.

I can modify a **SINGLE** run configuration to add the `-s` option and I get the behavior I want, but I want to globally modify the pytest runner to append the `-s` option.

For reference:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-py-test.html

Thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In the top-left of the IDE, next to the "run" and "debug" buttons, there is a dropdown menu that allows you to select one of your recent test runs. Go to "Edit Configurations..." -> "Templates" -> "Python tests" -> "pytest" and that preference pane allows you to globally edit the pytest configuration for all future runs.

Comment: not only it doesn't work, but also the answer is in the question.

Comment: You also need to set for the "Python tests" -> "Autodetect" template if you want it to work when you just click the green arrows.